# Scraping a page with node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to get the flights table for every city from a page but befor that i have to set search fields and hit the button and befor that i have to import captcha at the first page. The web site designed with .Net. I import the captcha by my self but i want to do the rest with nodejs.
This is what i'm doing. first, import the captcha and then from loaded page and by looking at the firebug, set request header and request url and then send using http.request with GET method to scrape the page with nodejs again. after that i get viewstate of the page and again usign firebug, set another request header and "post data" and request url and send them using http.request to scrape the final page. This information that i set using firebug, are fixed; i mean, urls, header options and post data. what i have to change is city name in post data.
But i get a page with empty table. if is possible, What should i do? (sorry for my bad english :) )
This is the url (in persian): http://sepehr.iranhrc.ir. 
Thanks in advance.

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var dataToAttach = {
    'ScriptManager1': 'uplFlightSearch|btnSubmit37756070715319',
    '__ASYNCPOST': true,
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__EVENTTARGET': '',
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    '__VIEWSTATE': '',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'E4CF65F9',
    'btnSubmit37756070715319': '?????',
    'dplFrom': 'THR',
    'dplReservationRouteType': 'RoundTrip_FixedDate',
    'dplTo': '0',
    'dplFlightAdults': '1',
    'dplFlightChilds': '0',
    'dplFlightInfants': '0',
    'txtCountUp': '00:26',
    'txtDepartureDate': '1394/04/02',
    'txtReturningDate': '1394/04/04'
};

var flightsSearchPageROs = {
    hostname: 'sepehr.iranhrc.ir',
    path: '/Systems/FA/Reservation/Flight_NewReservation_Search.aspx?qry=sbV7wBdq4B7yEk1yv0OpvmofQkdkbWH49Wjk6UIMGiw95zDjDGo0/ssWJH8Wjv1D',
    method: 'GET',
    headers:{
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=2iexj4pfxld4mdilfwttka2q;',
        'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'Host': 'sepehr.iranhrc.ir',
        'Referer': 'sepehr.iranhrc.ir'
    }
};

var resultsPageROs = {
    hostname: 'sepehr.iranhrc.ir',
    path: '/Systems/FA/Reservation/Flight_NewReservation_Search.aspx?action=display&rnd=2378726045210585',
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=o1ipad335qahuaahc25ngalr;',
        'Content-Length': '',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'Referer': 'http://sepehr.iranhrc.ir/Systems/FA/Reservation/Flight_NewReservation_Search.aspx',
        'Host': 'sepehr.iranhrc.ir',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
};

var flightsSearchPage = http.request(flightsSearchPageROs, function(response{
    var dataStream = '';
    var htmlCode = '';
    var date = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
        dataStream += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        htmlCode = cheerio.load(dataStream);
        secondDataToAttach.__VIEWSTATE = htmlCode("__VIEWSTATE").val();
        resultsPageROs.headers['Content-Length'] = querystring.stringify(dataToAttach).length;
        resultsPageRequest();
    });
});
flightsSearchPage.on('error', function(e){console.log("Error0: " + e.message);});
flightsSearchPage.end();

function resultsPageRequest(){
    var changingCitiesBoxResponse = http.request(resultsPageROs, function(response){
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        var dataStream = '';
        var htmlCode = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk){
            dataStream += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function(){
            htmlCode = cheerio.load(dataStream);
            console.log(htmlCode.html());
        });
        console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
    });
    changingCitiesBoxResponse.on('error', function(e){console.log("Error1: " + e.message);});
    changingCitiesBoxResponse.end(querystring.stringify(dataToAttach));
}
```

**EDIT**

One thing that i forgot to mention it was that, this is done in PHP with Curl and i looked at the code in curl part and done exactly like that with node and http.request. PHP returns correct answer but mine not.
And I used phantom as well.This is the code:

```
var url = "http://sepehr.iranhrc.ir/Systems/FA/Reservation/Flight_NewReservation_Search.aspx?action=display&rnd=4565721642440773";
var settings = {
    operation: "POST",
    encoding: "utf8",
    weak: false,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=2iexj4pfxld4mdilfwttka2q;',
        'Content-Length': '',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'Referer': 'http://sepehr.iranhrc.ir/Systems/FA/Reservation/Flight_NewReservation_Search.aspx?qry=sbV7wBdq4B7yEk1yv0OpvmofQkdkbWH49Wjk6UIMGiw95zDjDGo0/ssWJH8Wjv1D',
        'Host': 'sepehr.iranhrc.ir',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    data: querystring.stringify(secondDataToAttach)
};

phantom.create(function (ph){
  ph.createPage(function (page){
    page.open(url2, settings, function(status){
        console.log(status);
        page.evaluate(function(){ return document.body.innerHTML; }, function(result){
            console.log('Content ' + result);
            ph.exit();
        });
    });
  });
}, {dnodeOpts: {weak: false}
});
```

But i didn't get the answer.
And yes, it uses AJAX to send the request. According to Firebug:
[image]
The first request is sending a post data and the second one, i think is a redirect that gives the link to the result page(i used that link but no luck) and the third is the result page with the flight details that i can't get.
May be i used them wrong. How can i use these Three request to get flights table?

Comment: Giving negative is easy But teaching is difficult. It's required Patience, Knowledge and good treatment.
May be i can't express my question well enough. But if you that give me negetive, just be more patient and tell me what's wrong with my question, wouldn't be better (i'm not telling you, don't give me negetive). then i correct my question and get the answer that i need it and that's real help, isn't that?

Comment: Start logging stuff out and find the problem. Are you getting a response from your request? If you are getting page content, what about your cheerio load? Can you query it for parts of the page? Is the page the page you expected? Maybe your post isn't working? You need to verify everything is happening like you think it is.

Comment: Thank you @UltimateBrent. yes, i get the response but just a page without result table(flight details).In the response page, The fields filled according to my post data(like city field or flight date field) but there is no flight details table(that supposed to be under the fields). I'm talking about final request, no problem with the first and there is no problem with cheerio either.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the page you want the results from is loading them through a separate AJAX request, and a regular get request isn't going to get that. You'll need to either figure out what that separate request is and do it yourself, or scrape the page with something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) that can execute the javascript for the page.

First though, go to the page on your browser regularly and watch the network tab and locate that request that loads in the data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @UltimateBrent. But as you can see, i used that module. my problem is that, the result page is empty. I mean there is no flights table in the page.

Comment: Thank you @UltimateBrent and appreciate your Patience. I updated the question

Comment: Inspect the requests and see if any of them have the data you're looking for. From that Chrome tab, you can check the headers to see what variables are sent, and the response to see if it has your flight results. Some flight searches send one request to execute a search, and another to see if there are results, and that might be what's happening here, so be wary that it may take more than one request.